# Why we only can transmit a real signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency, continuous-signals, modulation, complex

i just wondering, why we always transmit a real signal but when we deal with a baseband signal we use a complex signal ? are this is related to up and down conversion of the signal (Because complex signal doesn't have symmetric properties when using FFT)

Comment: This has been discussed before on this website. Please search for similar questions.